# Why is it 'in the saddle' rather than 'on the saddle'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I regularly hear the phrase 'in the saddle' but 'on the saddle' seems more appropriate as you are literally on top of it, (I'm using the original definition of literally there!).

I can sit **in** an armchair.
A baby can sit **in** a high chair.
I can sit **in** a car.

Up to this point, it seems that if the object you are sat in/on surrounds you in some way, then you must sit **in** it.

I can sit **on** a plane (at least I've never heard someone say "I'm sitting in a plane right now"!), which is weird because you're actually inside the plane!

But i can only sit **on** a sofa, no one ever sits **in** a sofa.

So what gives? Is it just the fact that one option sounds better than the other, or is there some deeper understanding of the English language that I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both ["in the saddle" and "on the saddle"](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=saddle_N%20spec%20the%20sg_DET) are used. The difference lies in what you want to say. "On the saddle" is merely a description of the position, while "[in the saddle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saddle)" means "in control". I guess you could imagine an emperor sitting in his giant chair, compared with a commoner sitting on his/her little chair, for an analogy.

The same goes for "in the bed" and "on the bed". "On the bed" is a description of position, while "in the bed" implies in addition being covered by something (a sheet for example).

Comment: This answer is definitely in the saddle, thanks!

Comment: Generally speaking (there are always exceptions), *on* is used more literally, while *in* is used more figuratively.

Comment: I think one exception is what the op mentioned: "on the plane" vs "in the plane". "On the plane" suggests you are taking a flight, while "in" is more literally here.